# What is the XML schema to represent a string-to-string dictionary?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

Suppose I have a `Dictionary<string, string>` instance, like this one:

{ { "a", "1" }, { "b", "2" } }

There are several ways to represent it in XML:

```
<root>
  <item>
    <key>a</key>
    <value>1</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <key>b</key>
    <value>2</value>
  </item>
</root>
```

OR

```
<root>
  <item key="a" value="1"/>
  <item key="b" value="2"/>
</root>
```

OR

```
<root>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>2</b>
</root>
```

What is the XML schema to describe each of the representations?

Thanks.

Comment: IDEs such as oXygen and Stylus Studio have a tool that generates a plausible schema from an input document. It provides an instant answer to such questions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have neither.

Comment: Note that you won't be able to use any string with the 3rd representation (there are limits to element names), and it's only good if you have a limited number of keys. Also, you will have trouble extending your schema with the 2nd, for instance if you want to add values in different languages. The first solution is heavy but more flexible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [`xs:unique`](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_unique.asp) element.
For 1st XML appropriate XSD is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="item">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string"  />
                            <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:unique name="uniqueItem">
            <xs:selector xpath="item"/>
            <xs:field xpath="key"/>
        </xs:unique>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

For 2nd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="item">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="key" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:unique name="uniqueItem">
            <xs:selector xpath="item"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@key"/>
        </xs:unique>

    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

For 3rd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: +1 for the two schemas. What about the third one? It is the most compact and thus most attractive to me.

Comment: Is this the only way? Explicitly list all the keys? Aren't there a way to say that the element's name is the key?

Comment: I think for the 3rd case the OP wants anyElement with simple content.

Comment: @Dimitre, But whenever we need to explicitly define all elements, or I may be mistaken?

Comment: @Dimitre, `<xs:any processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded" />` it solves the problem. But how specify uniqueness? As I know we can't specify `<xs:field xpath="name()"/>` in XSD?

Comment: @polishchuk: My memories of XSD are a little rusty at the moment. We know for sure that there are cases that cannot be specified conveniently (or not at all) for any given schema language. In many cases people tend to use Schematron because of such reasons.

Comment: @Dimitre, It's clear. Any way, thanks for the reference to Schematron, nice to know.